# Starting Ubuntu from computer off will not start ethernet connection; ok after reboot

Tags: ethernet, reboot

Starting Ubuntu from computer off will not start the ethernet connection. It will however, start my connection on a reboot every time; this has happened through many versions of Ubuntu.

This may be the same as others but I never seem to see that on a reboot the connection restarts automatically.

I have tried a few things from other posts with no success.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: Same thing happens with my brother after a few dozen updates to his 12.04 LTS installation. What version are you running? Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Please specify the "few things" you have tried from other posts; how do you think people could know otherwise?

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg` when the ethernet card doesn't work and when it works?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?